# The java servlet calls never reaches the servlet

Tags: java, servlets, wildfly-10

I have a java web application which i have deployed in wildfly 10 web server. The application works fine for most of the time, but very unexpectedly the calls to the java servlet never reaches the servlet.

I became curious and analyzed the thread dump of the wildfly server in visualvm. Although i am not an expert in analyzing thread dumps, i expect that some thread locks are occurring due to which the task thread for that servlet call never executes; keeps waiting forever.

Right now i don't know whether this is a problem from the application side. I am suspecting that this is a problem with the servlet container configuration which i have set to default, or is this some wildfly bug?.., which i hope so isn't. Please reply.

This is my login servlet code:

```
 response.setContentType("application/json");
    UserInfo user = null;
    boolean authenticated = false;
    String message = "";
    String ipAddress = request.getHeader("X-FORWARDED-FOR");
    if (ipAddress == null) {
        ipAddress = request.getRemoteAddr();
    }

    try {
        ApplicationHelper.clearSession(request);
        String body = request.getReader().lines().reduce("", (accumulator, actual) -> accumulator + actual);
        HashMap inputDataMap = new ObjectMapper().readValue(body, HashMap.class);
        String userName = (String) inputDataMap.get("username");
        String password = (String) inputDataMap.get("password");
        user = UserDataProvider.verifyEncryptedAccount(userName, password);

        if (user != null) {
            UserDataProvider.updateLoginStatus(user.getIdKey(), request.getSession().getId(), ipAddress, true);
            request.getSession(true).setAttribute("userInfo", user);
            authenticated = true;
            message = MPHLTHConstants.Success;
        } else {
            throw new InsufficientAccessException("Insufficient access");
        }

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        authenticated = false;
        if (ex instanceof ApplicationException) {
            message = ex.getMessage();
        }
        ExceptionDataProvider.logException(ex, request, user);
    } finally {
        try {
            Response objResponse = new Response(user, message, authenticated, 1);
            Map<String, String[]> jsonFilters = new HashMap<>();
            jsonFilters.put("ResponseFilter", new String[0]);
            jsonFilters.put("UserInfoFilter", new String[0]);
            JSONHelper.writeJSONResponse(objResponse, response, jsonFilters);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ExceptionDataProvider.logException(ex, request, user);
        }
    }
```

These are the threads where i saw the locks, and i several of them at different times and these didn't change over time:

```
"default task-64" #206 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x000000001c59b800 nid=0x5608 waiting for monitor entry [0x000000001f8bd000]   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    at java.io.PrintStream.println(PrintStream.java:805)
    - waiting to lock <0x00000000e0058f58> (a java.io.PrintStream)
    at org.jboss.stdio.StdioContext$DelegatingPrintStream.println(StdioContext.java:474
```

and this one:

```
> "default task-61" #203 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x000000001c599000 nid=0x4934 runnable [0x000000001f5bd000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:326)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
    - locked <0x00000000e0aeb790> (a java.io.BufferedOutputStream)
    at java.io.PrintStream.write(PrintStream.java:482)
    - locked <0x00000000e0aeb770> (a java.io.PrintStream)
    at org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.UncloseableOutputStream.write(UncloseableOutputStream.java:44)
    at org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.UninterruptibleOutputStream.write(UninterruptibleOutputStream.java:84)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.writeBytes(StreamEncoder.java:221)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlushBuffer(StreamEncoder.java:291)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(StreamEncoder.java:295)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(StreamEncoder.java:141)
    - locked <0x00000000e0aeb738> (a java.io.OutputStreamWriter)
    at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(OutputStreamWriter.java:229)
    at java.io.BufferedWriter.flush(BufferedWriter.java:254)
    - locked <0x00000000e0aeb738> (a java.io.OutputStreamWriter)
    at org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.WriterHandler.safeFlush(WriterHandler.java:170)
    at org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.WriterHandler.flush(WriterHandler.java:139)
    - locked <0x00000000e0aeb700> (a java.lang.Object)
    at org.jboss.logmanager.ExtHandler.doPublish(ExtHandler.java:104)
    at org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.WriterHandler.doPublish(WriterHandler.java:67)
    - locked <0x00000000e0aeb700> (a java.lang.Object)
    at org.jboss.logmanager.ExtHandler.publish(ExtHandler.java:76)
    at org.jboss.logmanager.LoggerNode.publish(LoggerNode.java:314)
    at org.jboss.logmanager.LoggerNode.publish(LoggerNode.java:322)
    at org.jboss.logmanager.Logger.logRaw(Logger.java:850)
    at org.jboss.logmanager.Logger.log(Logger.java:596)
    at org.jboss.stdio.AbstractLoggingWriter.write(AbstractLoggingWriter.java:71)
    - locked <0x00000000e0058fb8> (a java.lang.StringBuilder)
    at org.jboss.stdio.WriterOutputStream.finish(WriterOutputStream.java:143)
    at org.jboss.stdio.WriterOutputStream.flush(WriterOutputStream.java:164)
    - locked <0x00000000e0059128> (a sun.nio.cs.SingleByte$Decoder)
    at java.io.PrintStream.write(PrintStream.java:482)
    - locked <0x00000000e0058f58> (a java.io.PrintStream)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.writeBytes(StreamEncoder.java:221)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlushBuffer(StreamEncoder.java:291)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flushBuffer(StreamEncoder.java:104)
    - locked <0x00000000e00579c0> (a java.io.OutputStreamWriter)
    at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flushBuffer(OutputStreamWriter.java:185)
    at java.io.PrintStream.newLine(PrintStream.java:546)
    - locked <0x00000000e0058f58> (a java.io.PrintStream)
    at java.io.PrintStream.println(PrintStream.java:807)
    - locked <0x00000000e0058f58> (a java.io.PrintStream)
    at org.jboss.stdio.StdioContext$DelegatingPrintStream.println(StdioContext.java:474)
```

Comment: Can you share any code with us?

Comment: What does it mean that "call does not reach the server?" What happens? HTTP status 403? May be 500?

Comment: Do you mean that *sometimes* the servlet doesn't receive the request? Otherwise I can't see how you can say that the application "works fine for most of the time".

Comment: Yeah, the application works fine usually until the servlet calls no longer reaches the servlet.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Is it the servlet code?

Comment: @AlexR  There is no response actually, when i check the XHR call, it shows as pending.

Comment: is your server in debug mode and stopped at some breakpoint in servlet?

Comment: @PrasadKharkar No the server isn't in debug mode.

Comment: @Vishnu Are there any errors in the WildFly log? I would suspect OutOfMemory or something similar to cause such freeze.

Comment: @JozefChocholacek Nope, no such errors, I run the standalone.bat from cmd, and when this issue happens, any println() statements from the application are only seen after i give control+C command, and then the servlet again works fine..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is finally resolved. It was found that the thread locks were occurring due to println() statements which were present in several places in the application. The logging subsytem in WildFly 10 and the println() statements were creating locks to the print output stream and eventually getting into a deadlock.

Comment: Why is it that Wildfly doesn't handle this correctly?

Comment: Because it wraps System.out and System.err exposing PrintStreams which perform 2 things: 1) writing to the jvm original Stream 2) write to stdout/stderr loggers (default console appender in wildfly).